# FOR JSON PATH produces unexpected xml declaration

Tags: json, xml, ssms

I'm in SSMS version 13.0.16106.4. I'm trying to retrieve the result of my query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY NEWID()
FOR JSON PATH
```

This produces a link in the results window to the JSON produced by the query. However, when I click the link, I get the following error:

> Unable to show XML. The following error happened:
> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 431.
> One solution is to increase the number of characters retrieved from the server for XML data. To change this setting, on the Tools menu, click Options.

I've tried increasing the data size limit for XML results, but it hasn't worked. It seems like SSMS sees the JSON as XML for some reason and may be trying to parse it as such.

Comment: Have you tried updating to a more recent version of SSMS?

Comment: I cannot. I'm on an enterprise system. Not in my power to update. Would this be something related to the version of SSMS?

Comment: *"Unable to show XML."* is an SSMS error, so yes.

Comment: So, I tried a similar query on my local machine (which has SSMS version 15.0.18142.0) and it worked properly. However, the table and data I used are different, so I cannot definitively say that was the problem. I also tried a different query on the older version of SSMS and got a working result:
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY NEWID()
FOR JSON PATH

Comment: As with any error, I would always suggest updating to a supported version first.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS doesn't handle JSON presentation well.

Please try Microsoft's Azure Data Studio. It knows how to handle JSON properly.
Azure Data Studio is automatically installed together with the latest versions of SSMS.

[Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here is an excerpt from the official MS documentation:

> Important
>
> Beginning with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.7, Azure Data
> Studio is automatically installed alongside SSMS. Users of SQL Server
> Management Studio are now able to benefit from the innovations and
> features in Azure Data Studio. Azure Data Studio is a cross-platform
> and open-source desktop tool for your environments, whether in the
> cloud, on-premises, or hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The data I was trying to query originally had XML in one of the columns as NVARCHAR. This caused problems with the parser as it assumed that it was malformed XML instead of JSON.

This can be faithfully reproduced in SSMS versions 13.0.16106.4 and 15.0.18142.0 using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Data>Test</Data>')
) A (XMLData)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Seems to be either a bug or an unintended consequence of storing XML as NVARCHAR.

EDIT:
Even the following query confuses the parser:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('<')
) A (XMLData)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Others have apparently run into this issue or similar issues with FOR JSON PATH:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39312790-json-preview-feature-is-broken-in-sql-server

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35650255-ssms-should-not-display-json-as-xml